# how to enter tilde in emacs with portuguese keyboard?

Tags: emacs

In every single other program I have ever used in the last 15 years across windows, osx and linux, I enter a tilde by pressing, the tilde key and then space. The Portuguese keyboard has a dedicated key for tilde where it is the primary character (no need for shift), it is used to compose ã and õ by pressing tilde then a or o. In emacs pressing tilde does nothing and posts "dead-tilde is undefined". How can I make emacs write a '~' when I press the '~' key in pt layout ?

Comment: @DaveGoten thank you, but that does not answer my question.

Comment: I can't test this myself since I don't have a Portuguese keyboard, but see if `(global-set-key (kbd "<dead-tilde>") 'self-insert-command)` helps.

Comment: @Chris that prints a square containing "201D8C"...

Comment: @miguel.negrao, it looks like `self-insert-command` is trying to insert something other than `~`, presumably whatever "dead tilde" literally is. See if the snippet in my answer below solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

I think this is a better solution: It should match your experience in other applications where `~o` gives `õ` and `~` followed by a space gives `~`.

Tell Emacs you wish to use the `portuguese-prefix` input method. Interactively, you can do `M-x set-input-method RET portuguese-prefix RET`. To make this permanent, add something like this to your config file:

```
(set-input-method 'portuguese-prefix)
```

**Original answer:**

`self-insert-command` doesn't seem to work well with dead keys.

Try this instead:

```
(defun my-insert-tilde ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "~"))

(global-set-key (kbd "<dead-tilde>") #'my-insert-tilde)
```

Comment: (set-input-method 'portuguese-prefix) doesn't work, it still says "dead-tilde is undefined" and does nothing". ~+a also only prints "a". I'm using a macbook pro, not sure that can be interacting here. I can see that pt mode is active, since the info bar as "pt" in it. Your other suggestion with defun works, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

add

```
(require 'iso-transl)
```

to Emacs init file (init.el). With this line tilde+space prints a tilde, and tilde+a prints ã.

This seems to be due to "[Emacs and some input method managers (ibus and SCIM) don’t work together](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeadKeys)".